# Oracle stored procedure - can I assign value to the variable in declaration block?

Tags: oracle

I am writing a stored procedure in oracle and I would like to assign a value to variable right from the start:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc
(
   param1
   , param2
)
AS
   variable1 INT AS SELECT MAX(value) FROM table WHERE field = param1;
BEGIN
...
```

Is it allowed or should I do it in executable block?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Errors, and I don't know if they occured due to my lack of procedure syntax knowledge or the fact that it is impossible to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Assuming this code is reflective of what you are trying to accomplish you might want to look at using a sequence and using the sequence's built in support for returning the next value in the sequence: sequence_name.nextval.  Any solution with max(value) will likely not produce the results you want in a concurrent environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle assign query values into variables like this...

```
SELECT MAX(value) INTO variable1 FROM table WHERE field = param1;
```

... and because it does, you can't initialize the variable to a query value in the declaration block. It has to be in the execution and/or exception blocks:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc
(
   param1; -- don't forget the data type here!
 , param2; -- or here!
)
AS
   variable1 INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(value) INTO variable1 FROM table WHERE field = param1;
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a local function instead of the variable:

```
create or replace procedure proc(param1 in varchar2) as
  function max_val return number is
    l_result number;
  begin
    select max(value)
      into l_result
      from t1
     where field = param1;
    return l_result;
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('max val for ' || param1 || ': ' || max_val);
end;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot also declare a local variable and assign the value of max_val to it, since declarations for functions are allowed only after declarations for variables.